# Templated Razor Delegates - Simpler HTML blocks

Tags: c#, templates, razor

I am working on some template generation stuff with Razor, and I wish to accomplish the following syntax:

```
        <div>
        @(Html.Use<LinkItem>("Story1",
        {
            <span>Something cool</span>
            <a href="@(item.Href)">@(item.Text)</a>
        }))
        </div>
```

or, even better

```
        <div>
        @(Html.Use<LinkItem>("Story1",
           <span>Something cool</span>
           <a href="@(item.Href)">@(item.Text)</a>
        ))
        </div>
```

Using Templated Razor Delegates, I got this:

```
        <div>
        @(Html.Use<LinkItem>("Story1",
           @<span>Something cool</span>
           @<a href="@item.Href">
                @item.Text
            </a>
        ))
        </div>
```

The problem is, I dont wanna have to add a @ before each tag in the block, and a `<text>` tag doesent look too good either.

Is it possible to achieve what I am looking for? Or maybe there are other ways?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest you could get is with `<text>` nodes:

```
@(Html.Use<LinkItem>("Story1", @<text>
    <span>Something cool</span>
    <a href="@(item.Href)">@(item.Text)</a>    
</text>))
```

Personally I prefer using display templates:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.SomeCollectionProperty)
```

and then I define the corresponding display template which is automatically rendered for each element of the collection (`~/Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates/SomeItem.cshtml`)

```
@model SomeItem
<span>Something cool</span>
<a href="@(Model.Href)">@Model.Text</a>
```

Comment: I thouht so - I went with this approach. Thanks!